# Openstack DB issues

Tags: database, openstack-horizon

Had a power issue and my openstack will not fully come up.

It is showing that I have VM's but from 5 years ago and not recent ones.

I need help bringing it up.

I am running an OLD version of the software.

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Field           | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| heatclient      | 1.1.0 |
| keystoneclient  | 2.3.1 |
| mistralclient   | 2.0.0 |
| novaclient      | 3.3.1 |
| openstackclient | 2.2.0 |
| senlinclient    | 0.4.0 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

This is on Ubuntu 14 or 16 depending on the machine attached.  I am trying to bring it back to life to be able to export and build a new system.  I inherited this system a year ago when the previous admin left.  I also talked to him, and he inherited back a few years before that.  He is also at a loss.

Comment: There's not really enough information here for us to help diagnose the problem, and it sounds like this may be an issue that really requires hands-on access to resolve. If you're seeing virtual machines from five years ago, it sounds like you may have an HA database that had an out-of-sync replica that has somehow become the primary. That is at least where I would start looking.

Comment: Thanks for the response..
Where would I start looking?
What other info would help?
Thanks!

Comment: If you look at your hypervisors, are there actually virtual machines running? Do they match what you see in the output of e.g. `openstack server list`? If there's a mismatch, you would start looking at your database servers. Are there more than one? Are they all running? If you connect to them individually do they have different data? If they're not running, can you copy the data files somewhere and start a database container to inspect them?

Comment: Honestly from the description here you're solidly in "take off and nuke the entire site from orbit" territory.

Comment: I am in the "take off and nuke the entire site from orbit".

Comment: Had this earlier:root@node-9:~# openstack server list
An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-bb5976c5-0743-46f5-9164-53ab8379bc34)

Now:
root@node-9:~# openstack server list
Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin
root@node-9:~#